# Adding text at the beginning of a file Java

Tags: java

This is a project for school, and I am having difficulty figuring out why it is this way. We are to create a program that will put data into a text file, but whenever I run my code, it will output to the file, but it will be at line 224, and not start at the beginning. Does anyone know why this may be? Here is my code

```
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import static java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
public class CreateCustomerFile
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Path file = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\brady\\IdeaProjects\\TestNew\\Customers.txt");
        String s = "000,      ,00000" + System.getProperty("line.separator");
        String[] array;
        byte[] data = s.getBytes();
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);
        FileChannel fc = null;
        final int recordSize = s.length(); //Size of record
        final int recordNums = 1000; //Number of records stored in file
        final String QUIT = "exit";
        String custString;
        int custNum;
        String lastName;
        String zipCode;
        String fileNum;
        try
        {
            OutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(file, CREATE));
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(output));
            for(int count = 0; count < recordNums; ++count)
                writer.write(s, 0, s.length());
            writer.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error message: " + e);
        }
        try
        {
            fc = (FileChannel)Files.newByteChannel(file, READ, WRITE);

            System.out.print("Enter customer number or 'exit' to quit >> ");
            custString = input.nextLine();
            while(!(custString.equalsIgnoreCase(QUIT)))
            {
                custNum = Integer.parseInt(custString);
                buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);
                fc.position((long) custNum * recordSize);
                fc.read(buffer);
                s = new String(data);
                array = s.split(",");
                fileNum = array[0];
                if(!(fileNum.equals("000")))
                    System.out.println("Sorry - customer " + custString + " already exists");
                else
                {
                    System.out.print("Enter the last name for customer #" + custNum + ": ");
                    lastName = input.nextLine();
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(lastName);
                    sb.append("      ");
                    sb.setLength(6);
                    lastName = sb.toString();
                    System.out.print("Enter zip code:  ");
                    zipCode = input.nextLine();
                    s = custString + "," + lastName + "," + zipCode + System.getProperty("line.separator");
                    data = s.getBytes();
                    buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);
                    fc.position((long) custNum * recordSize);
                    fc.write(buffer);
                }

                System.out.print("Enter next customer number or 'exit' to quit: ");
                custString = input.nextLine();
            }
            fc.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error message: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome. What did you use as your inputs?

Comment: I have voted this question to be closed since the problem  as described does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs more input validation, any user provided string input must be sized for the output field, no matter the input.

`lastName` is done correctly, but customer number and zip code are left to chance, and can throw off the record count in the file.

A customer id entered as `"1"` is 2 characters shorter than `"001"` thus upsetting the fixed length record for the remaining file.

Comment: Should have mentioned that the requirements for this, stated that we are to presume that the user will input the three-digit ID and five-digit zip code correctly, but we are to force the last name to be a six-digit string, that is why zip and ID do not have that on those.

Comment: In that case your code works perfectly.